# Extracting string between punctuation, when present

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract a string after a `:` or `;` and before a `;` if the 2nd punctuation is present, then to remove everything after a `;` if present. Goal result is a number.

The current code is able to do between `:` and `;` OR after `:` but cannot handle `;` alone or `:` alone.

Also, `gsub(|(OF 100); SEE NOTE)` isn't working, and I'm not sure why the initial `:` isn't being excluded and needs the gsub at all.

```r
test<-c("Score (ABC): 2 (of 100); see note","Amount of ABC; 30%","Presence of ABC: negative","ABC not tested") 
#works for :/;
toupper((regmatches(toupper(test), gregexpr(":\\s* \\K.*?(?=;)", toupper(test), perl=TRUE))))
#works for :
test<-toupper((regmatches(toupper(test), gregexpr(":\\s* (.*)", toupper(test), perl=TRUE))))
#removes extra characters:
test<-gsub(": |(OF 100); SEE NOTE|%|; ","",test)
#Negative to numeric:
test[grepl("NEGATIVE|<1",test)]<-0
test
```

Expected result: `2 30 0`

Comment: Could you show an example of what you would like to obtain?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/PTH606

Comment: I've updated the sample data to reflect an issue that I should have accounted for. In this case, numerical is numerical, negative is 0, but absence of the string (step prior to this query) and absence of : | ; should be NA, rather than negative/0. Such that the updated result should be: ## [1] 2  30  0  NA

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions.

The first two are base.  The first only uses very simple regular expressions.  The second is shorter and the regular expression is only a bit more complicated.  In both cases we return NA if there is no match but you can replace NAs with 0 (using `ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)` where `x` is the answer with NAs) afterwards if that is important to you.

The third is almost the same as the second but uses strapply in gsubfn. It returns 0 instead of NA.

**1) read.table** Replace all colons with semicolons and read it in as semicolon-separated fields.  Pick off the second such field and remove the first non-digit and everything after it.  Then convert what is left to numeric.

```
DF <- read.table(text = gsub(":", ";", test), 
  as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep = ";", strip.white = TRUE)
as.numeric(sub("\\D.*", "", DF$V2))
##[1]  2 30 NA
```

**2) strcapture**   Match from the start characters which are not colon or semicolon and then match a colon or semicolon and then match a space and finally capture digits.  Return the captured digits converted to numeric.

```
strcapture("^[^:;]+[;:] (\\d+)", test, list(num = numeric(0)))$num
##[1]  2 30 NA
```

**3) strapply**  Using the same pattern as in (2) convert the match to numeric and return 0 if the match is empty.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(test, "^[^:;]+[;:] (\\d+)", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE, empty = 0)
## [1]  2 30  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
out <- gsub('(^.+?[;:][^0-9]+)(\\d+)(.*$)|^.+', '\\2', test)
out[out == ''] <- 0
as.numeric(out)

## [1] 2  30  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP's description (italics is mine):

> extract a string after a : or ; and before a ; if the 2nd punctuation is present, *then to remove everything after a ; if present.* Goal result is a number.

I think some of the other suggestions may miss that italicized criteria.  So here is the OP's test set with one extra condition at the end to test that:

```
test<-c( "Score (ABC): 2 (of 100); see note",
         "Amount of ABC; 30%",
         "Presence of ABC: negative",
         "...and before a ; if the second punctuation is present, then remove everything after a ; if present [so 666 should not be returned]")
```

### One-liner to return results as requested:

```
sub( pattern='.+?[:;]\\D*?[^;](\\d*).*?;*.*', 
     replacement='\\1', 
     x=test, perl=TRUE)
```

#### Results matching OP's request:

```
[1] "2"  "30" ""   ""
```

If the OP really wants an integer with zeros where no match is found, set the sub() replacement = `'0\\1'` and wrap with `as.integer()` as follows:

```
as.integer( gsub( pattern='.+?[:;]\\D*?[^;](\\d*).*?;*.*', 
                  replacement='0\\1', 
                   x=test, perl=TRUE) )
```

Result:

```
[1]  2 30  0  0
```

#### Fully working online R (R 3.3.2) example:

https://ideone.com/TTuKzG

#### Regexp explanation

OP wants to find just one match in a string so the `sub()` function  works just fine.

Technique for using `sub()` is to make a pattern that matches all strings, but use a capture group in the middle to capture *zero or more* digits if conditions around it are met.

The pattern `.+?[:;]\\D*?[^;](\\d*).*?;*.*` is read as follows

- `.+?` Match any character (except for line terminators) `+` between one and unlimited times `?` as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `[:;]` Match a single character in the list between the square brackets, in this case `:` or `;`
- `\\D` Match any character that's NOT a digit (equal to [^0-9])
- `*?` Quantifier `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times `?` as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `[^;]` The `^` hat as first character between square brackets means: Match a single character NOT present in the list between the square brackets, in this case match any character NOT `;`
- `(\d*)` Everything between curved brackets is a capturing group - this is the 1st capturing croup: `\\d*` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible(greedy)
- `;*` Match the `;` character `*` **between zero and unlimited times** [so ; does not have to be present *but* is matched if it is there: This is the key to excluding anything after the second delimiter as the OP requested]
- `.*` Match any character `*` between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible (greedy) [so picks up everything to the end of the line]

The replacement = `\\1` refers to the 1st capture group in our pattern.  We replace everything that was matched by the pattern with what we found in the capture group. `\\d*` can match no digits, so will return an empty string if there is no number found where we are expecting it.